# Creating calculated result set based on looping through 2 columns and multiplying

Tags: sql

I have 2 columns in a sql database that are integers (in separate tables), i'll simplify my problem to explain. I have to replicate what has been done in excel in SQL and don't know how to do it. In basic terms I have to loop through all of one table multiplying all by the first record in the 2nd table, then the 2nd row and so on. Building up a table. I don't know how to do this does anyone have any ideas? Example below.

```
Column A:|   Column B:
12       |   36
24       |   89
26
```

The result output should a table like:

```
A   |   B
432 |   1068
864 |   2136
936 |   2314
```

So 36 has been multiplied by 12, 24 then 26 to create the first column and then 89 multiplied by 12, 24 then 26 to create the 2nd column and so on
The reality columns have 400+ rows to multiply by so the result is a huge table, how can i do this looping through and adding columns to build a calculated table. Hope that makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand you. Can you send the code in "Code Sample" block, or attach a screenshot?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think I've sorted it with a cross join and can't believe it was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont know how your database looks like here is a generic code that could work for you.

```
select tableA.colA, tableB.colb, (tableA.colA*tableB.colB) as colC 
from tableA 
join tableB (on ... if there is something to join on).
```

This will give you three columns though, the two original columns and the third multiplied column. You could ofcourse remove colA and colB oif you dont need them, they are just there for reference.

this code should work in most sql-languages.

Comment: Join is not needed here. Simply going
`select table1.colA, table2.colB, table1.colA*table2.colB as result from table1, table2` will give the mentioned output.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help, I sorted out the problem with a cross join